# Json Parsing object inside Object getting error

Tags: android, json

-- I know parsing, i have successfully parsed below data, but when web-service is upgraded i need to parse object inside object. 
- I tried many example but getting error.

Code for Parsing :

```
private final String KEY_SUCCESS = "status";
    private final String KEY_MSG = "Message";
    private final String KEY_MSG1 = "Message";
    //   private final String KEY_AddressList = "addressList";
    private final String KEY_USERINFO = "user_info";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;

    private final String KEY_DATA = "data";
    private final String KEY_USERDATA = "userdata";

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getList(String response) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            if (jsonObject.getString(KEY_SUCCESS).equals("true")) {

                arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    //  JSONObject job = obj.getJSONObject("User");

                    Log.d("obj", obj.toString());


                    String user_id = obj.getString(Constants.Params.ID);
                    String createdate = obj.getStringAndyConstants.Params.CREATEDDATE);
                    String postImage = obj.getString(Constants.Params.IMAGE);



                    map.put(AndyConstants.Params.ID, user_id);
                   map.put(AndyConstants.Params.CREATEDDATE, createdate);
                    map.put(AndyConstants.Params.IMAGE, postImage);

   JSONObject objectDetails2 = obj.getJSONObject(KEY_DATA);

                    JSONArray jsonArrayUser = objectDetails2.getJSONArray("userdata");
                    for (int j = 0; j < jsonArrayUser.length(); j++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> mapUser = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject businessObject = jsonArrayUser.getJSONObject(j);
                        Log.d("obj", businessObject.toString());
                    }


                    Log.d("map", map.toString());
                    arraylist.add(map);

                }

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return arraylist;
    }
```

Error Log :

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for data


E/array: []
E/adapter: []
```

Json :

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Successfully add Post",
    "data": [{

        "user_id": "46",
        "image": "",
        "createdate": "2016-05-11 06:05:12",
        "userdata": {
            "first_name": "Alpha",
            "last_name": "Gamma",
            "image": "http:\/\/abcd.net\/abcd\/uploads\/100520161005191462941615032.jpg"
        }
    }
```

Comment: you have used some Keys whose values are unknown like KEY_SUCCESS, KEY_DATA . please add those values and formate your code so that is easy to read

Comment: Your json missing ] } at the end of file

Comment: @Dixit Panchal, its not missing, mistake in copy paste

Comment: `JsonArray jsonArray=new jsonArray(jsonObject.getString(""data))` than `JsonObject newObj=jsonArray.getJsonObject(position);`

Comment: @Shubhank, i have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need this line

```
   JSONObject objectDetails2 = obj.getJSONObject(KEY_DATA);
```

and change

```
  JSONArray jsonArrayUser = objectDetails2.getJSONArray("userdata");
```

to

```
  JSONObject userData = obj.getJSONObject("userdata");
  String firstName = userData.getString("first_name");
  String lastName  = userData.getString("last_name");
```

As you can see from the JSON

```
"data":
     [{"user_id":"46",
        "image":"",
           "createdate":"2016-05-11 06:05:12",
           "userdata":{"first_name
```

> data is having the object [ which denotes an Array while userData shows a { which is a JSONObject

Comment: JSONObject businessObject = jsonArrayUser.getJSONObject(j); What i have to do with this

Comment: first i would suggest to go to jsonlint.com and paste your json. it will process and show it indented with line break. edit your question and paste that so it is easy to explain

Comment: can u plz help me with my code .. proper output. plz

Comment: what is the output you want ?

Comment: i am getting object data successfully, but i want object userdata(everything inside userdata)

Comment: you will it in jsonArrayUser in the code i gave, let me update my answer

Comment: maybe you have done something wrong when using my code. can you edit your question to show your new code ?

Answer (score 0):

I notice that your JSON has some errors. is this the complete Json response?

Because JSON response should be something like this:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Successfully add Post",
    "data": [{

        "user_id": "46",
        "image": "",
        "createdate": "2016-05-11 06:05:12",
        "userdata": {
            "first_name": "Alpha",
            "last_name": "Gamma",
            "image": "http:\/\/abcd.net\/abcd\/uploads\/100520161005191462941615032.jpg"
        }
    }]
}
```

You will notice that there is no close for `[` after `userdata` in your Json.